# Relation between three vectors on a sphere under some conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

**QUESTION:** Consider a sphere with radius 1 and centre $O$. There are three points on the surface of the sphere, $A$, $B$ and $C$. A vector $\textbf{v}$ is perpendicular to the plane through $A$, $B$ and $C$. The angle between $\overrightarrow{OA}$ and $\textbf{v}$ is $\alpha$, the angle between $\overrightarrow{OB}$ and $\textbf{v}$ is $\beta$ and the angle between $\overrightarrow{OC}$ and $\textbf{v}$ is $\gamma$. Find a relation between $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

**A Note:** Although cross products could be incredibly useful, I'm looking for a method without using them. If it cannot be done without them, I'll be happy to accept an answer with it, although it't not ideal.

**My attempts:**

> Considering right triangles with a side as the altitude and equating the expressions for the altitudes, although I have no clue where to go from there.
> I also considered finding equations that related the magnitudes of the vectors to the altitude with the edges of the tetrahedron between the points $A$, $B$, $C$, $O$, although I also couldn't get anywhere with that.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: "I'm looking for a method without using them." Any reason? $v$ is perpendicular to the plane, so one requires the cross product in one way or another.

Comment: Good question – I've made an edit to the post saying that if there's no other easy way, then I'll be happy to accept a method with cross products. I apologise for that. The reason is because the course I'm doing doesn't use them. I've written this question for a friend for practise and I'm actually unsure how to actually obtain a relation.

Comment: Do you know about spherical triangle

Comment: Yes I do, Akalanka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the plane of $ABC$ to be the $x-y$ plane, and let the centre of the sphere be $P$ on the $z$-axis. $O$ is now the origin. Then $A,B,C$ are three points on the plane.

Consider triangles $OPA$, $OPB$, $OPC$. Their hypotenuse have length 1, so $AO=1=BO=CO$. Then $\cos\alpha=OP/AO=OP/BO=\cos\beta$. Hence the angles are all equal, $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$.